# how to use javascript alert so that user can choose

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to add an alert box so that the user can choose either **Yes or No** or **Ok and Cancel**, but it is not working correctly. It is my first time I am trying to do this. I am using visual studio 2010. I am not sure if my code is correct. Can anyone please guide me if I am mistaken.

**This is my code:**

```
private void AlertWithOption()
  {
     Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>");
     Response.Write("function onsub() ");
     Response.Write("{ ");
     Response.Write("var where_to= confirm: (\"Are You sure?\")");
     Response.Write("if (where_to== true)");
     Response.Write("{ ");
     Response.Write("return true");
     Response.Write(" }");
     Response.Write("else ");
     Response.Write("{");
     Response.Write("return false;");
     Response.Write(" } ");
     Response.Write("} ");
     Response.Write("</script>");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would try changing this:

```
Response.Write("var where_to= confirm: (\"Are You sure?\")");
```

to this:

```
Response.Write("var where_to= confirm(\"Are You sure?\")");
```

(The method is `confirm()` and not `confirm:()`)

Comment: I changed that but it didn't work. Just for your information I am working in a .NET enviroment using c sharp.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you had an extra colon in your code. However, there is no need for the lengthy if/then logic, as the `confirm` javascript method returns a boolean. Your code can be condensed to 3 lines:

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("function onsub() { return confirm(\"are you sure?\"); }");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: I have to do a database check which is done in c sharp not just link that function to a button clicked event. thanks

Answer (score 1):

modify this line of code-> Response.Write("var where_to= confirm: (\"Are You sure?\")");
try this->Response.Write("var where_to= confirm ("Are You sure?")");

Comment: try your code here--> http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

Answer (score 1):

method confirm() is correct but the string inside should be within double quotes that is confirm("Are You Sure?");

Answer (score 1):

Use `confirm()` function.

```
private void AlertWithOption()
  {
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>");
    Response.Write("function onsub() ");
    Response.Write("{ ");
    Response.Write("return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")");
    Response.Write("} ");
    Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

I think you are doing mistake in the syntax of the `confirm()`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want the colon after the confirm, you could do it like this

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>");
Response.Write("function onsub() ");
Response.Write("{ ");
Response.Write("return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")");
Response.Write("} ");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: Just for your information I am working in a .NET enviroment using c sharp

Comment: I've edited my code to show how it would be done using your example

Comment: -I have to do a database check which is done in c sharp not just link that function to a button clicked event. thanks